# What's the pronunciation of 1点差?

Tags: pronunciation, counters

Intuitively, I would guess it's 「いってんさ」, but I could image 「いちてんさ」just as well.

For bonus points: is there any reference or dictionary that explains the pronunciation of numbers with counters (beyond the obvious ones taught in beginner's courses)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word#Euphonic_changes

Comment: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E6%95%B0%E8%A9%9E#.E4.B8.80.E8.A6.A7

Answer (score 2):

I also believe it is いってんさ。

It means a one point difference (or gap)

一点、二点 etc ＝one point, two point etc

差＝difference, eg 差がある＝there is a difference or gap.

Possibly

> てんさ／点差 | the difference in points

is more common than 一点差　（？）eg:

> 2点の点差で負けた｜We lost the game by two points.
>
> ライオンズは点差を広げた｜The Lions widened their lead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's `いってんさ` as you said.